# Can additional columns be added to a Count Query

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have data from two spreadsheets where I need to compare the quantities of software installed and purchased.   The common fields are prefix and client across the two spreadsheets, but there is no unique identifier.

I have created 3 tables. A Primary Key in Client (Client_ID) and foreign keys in Installed and Purchased.  # Primary *  Foreign

TABLES:-

```
Client - Client.Client_ID#, Client.Client

Installed - Installed.Client_ID*, Installed.Prefix, Installed.Publisher, Installed.Version,Installed.Amount

Purchased -Purchase.Client_ID*, Purchase.Prefix, Purchase.Status, Purchase.Qty
```

Part of the issue that I am having is that the most of the records/rows are list multiple times. E.g  Product Y is recorded as 20 line items/ rows rather that Y Quantity 20.

I want to calculate the count (Installed.Amount) based on the prefix AND client_ID.

So far I can only calculate the count on the prefix and not client_ID. Is it possible to combine columns so the query will result the quantity of the Prefix and additional columns.

Query:-

```
SELECT Installed.Prefix, Count(Installed.Amount) AS PrefixQuantity
FROM Installed 
GROUP BY Installed.Prefix;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Installed.Client_ID, Installed.Prefix, COUNT(Installed.Amount)
AS PrefixQuantity FROM Installed GROUP BY Installed.Client_ID, Installed.Prefix
```

---

BTW, I think you should use:

```
SELECT Installed.Client_ID, Installed.Prefix, SUM(Installed.Amount)
AS PrefixQuantity FROM Installed GROUP BY Installed.Client_ID, Installed.Prefix
```

This will give correct results even if the Amount column has a value of more than 1.

Comment: Many Thanks much appreciated. Now successfully added additional columns to count/sum query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   
       client c
       INNER JOIN purchase p
       ON c.client_id = p.client_id 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT installed.prefix, 
                          installed.client_id, 
                          COUNT(installed.amount) prefixquantity 
                   FROM   installed 
                   GROUP  BY installed.prefix, 
                             installed.client_id) counts 
         ON c.client_id = counts.client_id
```